# changing list of character to list int in C++

Tags: c++, list, algorithm

i try to change from string to list of char, than list of char change to list int. here is my code

```
int main() {
    std::string int1 = "1122334455";
    std::list<char> listChars(int1.begin(), int1.end());
    std::list<int> intList(listChars.begin(), listChars.end());
    for(const auto& elem: intList){
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
}
```

The result of this is

```
49 49 50 50 51 51 52 52 53 53
```

not

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

the second method i try to use is

```
void printListInt(std::list<int>& listInt){
    for(int i:listInt){
        std::cout << i;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
// make string "Hello World" and string "1122334455"
std::string str1 = "Hello World";
std::string int1 = "1122334455";

std::list<char> listChars(str1.begin(), str1.end());
std::list<char> listCharInt(int1.begin(), int1.end());

std::list<int> listInt(listCharInt.begin(), listCharInt.end());
printListInt(listInt);
}
```

I understand that it has to -48 to show the expected result, but is there possibility that i don't use for to recalculate list int?

Comment: If you want to print an int as a char you need to cast it to one or do the math to convert the ascii value to the actual numerical value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the output is correct because you had declared a string i.e, `std::string int1 = "1122334455";` and then you are trying to print it as `integer` then the compiler will automatically **typecast** it according to the ASCII value of all characters of the string.

ASCII value of "0" is 48

ASCII value of "1" is 49

ASCII value of "2" is 50

ASCII value of "3" is 51

.
.
ASCII value of "9" is 57

So you are getting the first output as

`49 49 50 50 51 51 52 52 53 53`  
Because it's being printed after *typecasting* from char/string to int.

If you want to print
`1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5` 
then there are different approach to achieve that, here is one of them

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string int1 = "1122334455";
    // std::list<char> listChars(int1.begin(), int1.end());
    std::list<char> intList;
    for (char c: int1) {
        intList.push_back(c);
    }
    for(const auto& elem: intList){
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OR, if you print or store the entire string into **Integer List** then simply subtract with the ascii value of 0 (i.e, 48)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    std::string int1 = "1122334455";
    std::list<char> listChars(int1.begin(), int1.end());
    std::list<int> intList(listChars.begin(), listChars.end());
    for(const auto& elem: intList){
        std::cout << elem-48 << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example the standard algorithm `std::transform`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string int1 = "1122334455";

    std::list<char> listChars( std::begin( int1 ), std::end( int1 ) );

    std::list<int> intList;

    std::transform( std::begin( listChars ), std::end( listChars ), 
                    std::back_inserter( intList ),
                    [ ]( const auto &c ) { return c - '0'; } );
 
    for(const auto& elem: intList)
    {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

Comment: thank you, let me see documentation std::transform..

Answer (score 0):

change from this  `for(const auto& elem: intList)` to `for(const char& elem: intList)`, it  will work fine.

because the auto is replaced by int and you are printing the character **ASCII** value.